# Icon + Text Hover

Tags: html, css

```css
.menu-items{
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.menu-items span{
    height: 31px;
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.47;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #242b39;
    margin-left: 22px;
}

.menu-items li{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.menu-items li:hover{
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #f1f4f8;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="menu-items">
                <li><img src="./images/online.png"><span>Customer Overview</span></li>
                <li><img src="./images/list-dot.png"><span>Reports</span></li>
                <li><img src="./images/file-add.png"><span>File transcodings</span></li>
                <li><img src="./images/notification.png"><span>Notification center</span></li>
</ul>
```

Hello,

I run into a problem where I need to get Icon and Text together and when hovering cover the whole thing equaly.

When I hover over it now on the side of the icon it gets stuck right to the icon but I add padding it messed the whole thing up.

Is there some prefered way to do that?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sup, I think you added the padding to the wrong element/class, cause i did it and it looks right as rain.

```css
.menu-items{
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.menu-items span{
    height: 31px;
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.47;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #242b39;
    margin-left: 22px;
}

.menu-items li{
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.menu-items li:hover{
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #f1f4f8;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <ul class="menu-items">
        <li><img src="./images/online.png"><span>Customer Overview</span></li>
        <li><img src="./images/list-dot.png"><span>Reports</span></li>
        <li><img src="./images/file-add.png"><span>File transcodings</span></li>
        <li><img src="./images/notification.png"><span>Notification center</span></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Yea. That is better. Thank you. Do you know a way to align that text better to img? I know you dont see that img but i needed centered to to it. Its kinda down in comparison to that img.

Comment: Could you perhaps link an example of your image so we can import it into the HTML and test CSS on it?

Comment: Happy to help! Don't forget to mark as the answer, so it helps other people. And yes, you can easily do that by using on the `<li>` the `display: flex` propertie, and `align-items: center`, so it aligns your content on the center on the Y axis, "vertically"

Comment: Hey! I sadly don't understand your language...Could you say it again in English?

Comment: @nejc26 Could you please send me your contact info? I need help with something and asking questions one by one here is hard.

Comment: if you want more help, here is my discord andreee#6781